# PHP: Obtain bidirectional stream

Tags: php, apache, sockets

How would I obtain a `bidirectional stream` in PHP to a client through Apache?
I control both the server and the client.

The client does not parse HTML content of any kind. It just needs to listen and respond dynamically to commands streamed to it.

I do not want to use long polling. I need the socket to remain open **and** accessible read/write within PHP.

I also do not want to open another port (It has to run through `port 80`)

The client has full socket control already. I was thinking I could emulate a file upload feature but am unsure if this would work.

How would I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web Sockets http://socketo.me/

Comment: This uses another port... Which I do not want... Sadly.